# Many compilation errors in all projects after Java update

Tags: java, updates

jre1.8 now appears in eclipse however my old jres (Except jre6) now say they are unbound (I have no idea what that means but now they don't work). I don't really care which jre I use but the new one (which has now defaulted on eclipse) brings up compilation errors for anything to do with JComponent (It asks me to configure the build path). 
I would post screenshots but I am a newbie here and I am not allowed.

I've just realised adding both the new jre and jre6 (my only working old one) fixes the problem. However its not a very clean solution and I would like an answer as to why the new jre doesn't know what a JComponent is!

Comment: "*I would post screenshots but I am a newbie here and I am not allowed*" post link to image. We can pit it in your question for you.

Comment: i forgot to ask: what version of eclipse do you use? jdt 8 is supported since Luna officially.

Comment: Yep that was the problem. I have been using eclipse indigo which has a compilation level only up to java 1.6. I am using kepler now (buried in the depths of my hdd) and jre1.8 works fine now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't have to post a screenshot, simply copy paste errors/stacktraces from the command line (as text)...

Comment: If using a different Version of Eclipse fixed your Problem, you should add that as an answer and accept it. So it can be valuable to others sharing the same Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that the new JRE doesn't recognize it's classes, that's just the symptom you're experiencing.
The cause is Eclipse, which then reports the JRE Runtime Library as unbound. The solution to this problem may be to remove the old unbound library from your build path and then add it again via
`Project(right click) -> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries`.

Removing on old System Library:
[image: remove JRE library]

How to add a new JRE Runtime System Library:
[image: Add Runtime library]

Selecting a runtime:
[image: eelecting jre]

Comment: This doesn't work, when I add the old library again it is still "unbound". When I add it it also says "No JREs in workspace compatible with specified execution environment: JavaSE-1.7". jre1.8 by itself still comes up with the compilation errors mentioned, after readding that as well. Do you think reinstalling jre1.8 would help?

Comment: @Kenta can you set the compilation level to Java1.8? maybe your version of eclipse doesn't support jdk8.

Comment: Yep that was the problem. I have been using eclipse indigo which has a compilation level only up to java 1.6. I am using kepler now (buried in the depths of my hdd) and jre1.8 works fine now. Thanks for your help.